# member control panel channel entry field relationship permissions

Tags: members, relationships, control-panel, entry, permissions

I am trying to give members access to the control panel so that they can publish edit their own entries. Say I have Channel A and Channel B. It is easy to setup EE so that each member can only edit the entries they create but say Channel B has a relationship field to Channel A.  There does not seem to be a way to restriction the entries in the relationship field to the entries from Channel A that the current user created just to the to the users group.  Which would let them select entries from Channel A that they did not create.

I realize I could build all this functionality in front end templates but would really rather not since the Channel A fields has a lot of grids and relationships to other channels as well.

So is there a way in EE to set this up or is there a plugin that allows for this type of permissions in the relationship field type?